# PineScript - ATR % Stoploss

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

I want to add ATR stoploss when strategy placed/detected an entry. so far I came up with this script:

```
@version=4    
// Stop Loss inputs atr     
longLossPerc = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)",type=input.float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01    
atrLength = input(title="ATR Length", type=input.integer, defval=6, minval=1)
userStructure = input(title="Use Structure", type=input.bool, defval=true)    
lookback = input(title="How far to look back for High/Low",type=input.integer, defval=7, minval=1)    
atrStopMultiplier = input(title="ATR x ? ", type=input.float, defval=1.0, minval=0.1)    
longStopPrice = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - longLossPerc)

// calculate data atr    
atr=atr(atrLength)    
longStop = (userStructure ? lowest(low, lookback) : close) - atr * atrStopMultiplier    
shortStop = (userStructure ? highest(high,lookback) : close) + atr * atrStopMultiplier

// plot atr Long/Short    
plot(longStop, color=color.green, style=plot.style_linebr, title="Long Trailing Stop-ATR")    
plot(shortStop, color=color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, title="Short Trailing Stop-ATR")
```

---

My problem is, I don't know how can I relate/connect this script to my script argument. Do I have to make a new variable, and then insert it in my strategy.close?

```
strategy.entry("LongA", strategy.long,1, when= x and y)    
strategy.close("LongA", when= z or t )
```

Note: x,y,z,t are predefined variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `strategy.exit()` function. It has `stop` and `loss` parameters.

> ***loss (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop loss (specified in
> ticks). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market
> position when the specified amount of loss (in ticks) is reached. The
> default value is 'NaN'.
>
> ***stop (series int/float)*** An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a
> specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit
> market position at the specified price (or worse). Priority of the
> parameter 'stop' is higher than priority of the parameter 'loss'
> ('stop' is used instead of 'loss', if its value is not 'NaN'). The
> default value is 'NaN'.

```
strategy.entry("LongA", strategy.long,1, when= x and y)
strategy.exit("Long Exit", "LongA", loss=longStop)
```

Comment: But can I also add an exit variable to strategy.exit? 
ex: 
strategy.exit("Long Exit", "LongA", loss=longStop, when= b)

so I want the Long entry to close when variable "b" is true, otherwise, it should stay in the trade until the ATR stoploss (Which is calculated only from the entry candle) is True.

Comment: Yes, `strategy.exit` has a `when`parameter so that you can have conditions.

Comment: okay, Thanks for the help!